# After successfully connecting to Google Contacts API via php, how/what do I store in database to reconnect later?

Tags: php, google-api, google-contacts-api

So here's the deal.

I've connected to Google contact's api via php, stored everything in sessions, and retrieved a list of contacts.

What I want is to store all the necessary tokens in a database, and retrieve them at a later time to re-use them on the same user. I can't figure out what information to store... I've attempted storing every little item from the session into a database and reloading it when I try to reconnect to the api, but always get one error or another because my tokens aren't correct.

I imagine the answer is simple to someone who understands OAuth well - it's really just a question of what do I store.

Code below:

```
<?php
session_start();

include_once "../oauth-php/library/OAuthStore.php";
include_once "../oauth-php/library/OAuthRequester.php";

global $db;

$userid=$_SESSION['userid'];

define("GOOGLE_CONSUMER_KEY", "website.com"); // 
define("GOOGLE_CONSUMER_SECRET", "----------------------"); // 

define("GOOGLE_OAUTH_HOST", "https://www.google.com");
define("GOOGLE_REQUEST_TOKEN_URL", GOOGLE_OAUTH_HOST . "/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken");
define("GOOGLE_AUTHORIZE_URL", GOOGLE_OAUTH_HOST . "/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
define("GOOGLE_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL", GOOGLE_OAUTH_HOST . "/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");

define('OAUTH_TMP_DIR', function_exists('sys_get_temp_dir') ? sys_get_temp_dir() : realpath($_ENV["TMP"]));

//  Init the OAuthStore
$options = array(
 'consumer_key' => GOOGLE_CONSUMER_KEY, 
 'consumer_secret' => GOOGLE_CONSUMER_SECRET,
 'server_uri' => GOOGLE_OAUTH_HOST,
 'request_token_uri' => GOOGLE_REQUEST_TOKEN_URL,
 'authorize_uri' => GOOGLE_AUTHORIZE_URL,
 'access_token_uri' => GOOGLE_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL
);

OAuthStore::instance("Session", $options);


try
{
 //  STEP 1:  If we do not have an OAuth token yet, go get one
 if (empty($_GET["oauth_token"]))
 {
  $getAuthTokenParams = array('scope' => 
   'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/',
   'xoauth_displayname' => 'My web app',
   'oauth_callback' => 'http://website.com/google.php');

  // get a request token
  $tokenResultParams = OAuthRequester::requestRequestToken(GOOGLE_CONSUMER_KEY, 0, $getAuthTokenParams);
  //  redirect to the google authorization page, they will redirect back
  header("Location: " . GOOGLE_AUTHORIZE_URL . "?btmpl=mobile&oauth_token=" . $tokenResultParams['token']);
 }
 else {
  //  STEP 2:  Get an access token
  $oauthToken = $_GET["oauth_token"];
  $oauthVerifier = $_GET["oauth_verifier"];
  $tokenResultParams = $_GET;

  //$db->query("UPDATE gmkeys SET token='$oauthToken', secrettoken='$oauthVerifier'");
  try {
      OAuthRequester::requestAccessToken(GOOGLE_CONSUMER_KEY, $oauthToken, 0, 'POST', $_GET);
  }
  catch (OAuthException2 $e)
  {
   var_dump($e);
      // Something wrong with the oauth_token.
      // Could be:
      // 1. Was already ok
      // 2. We were not authorized
      return;
  }

  // make the request.
  $request = new OAuthRequester("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results=1000&group=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fm8%2Ffeeds%2Fgroups%2Fusernamehere%40gmail.com%2Fbase%2F6", 'GET', $tokenResultParams);


  $result = $request->doRequest(0);
  if ($result['code'] == 200) 
  {
   $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($result['body']);
   ...
  }
  else 
  {
   echo 'Error';
  }
 }
}
catch(OAuthException2 $e) {
 echo "OAuthException:  " . $e->getMessage();
 var_dump($e);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The access_token and the request_token strings